# Is there any way to exec into an initContainer in Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers

I have a init container in which I'm storing file but while running it's showing the file is not present.
Is there any way I can exec inside init container and check where the file is being stored.

Answer (score 7):

Use `kubectl describe <pod>` to get the id of the initContainer you need to exec into then use `kubectl exec -ti <pod> -c <container> sh` to access its shell. You may need to add some kind of delay, like `sleep` to the initContainer to access it before it completes or fails.